# R & XML2: Remove XML attributes

Tags: r, xml2

I have an XML document in variable `doc`. `xml_attr(doc, "attr")` for example prints out the value `200` from its attribute `attr="200"`.

`xml_set_attr(doc, "attr", "")` does remove the value, but I want to remove the `attr` attribute from the tag so the document looks like:

`<tag></tag>` instead of

`<tag attr></tag>` or

`<tag attr=""></tag>`

---

Does xml2 have a function for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning `NULL` to remove the attribute:

```
library(xml2)
(doc <- read_xml("<tag value='200'></tag>"))
# {xml_document}
# <tag value="200">
xml_set_attr(doc, "value", NULL)
doc
# {xml_document}
# <tag>
```